# SQL Query DISTINCT causes Grand Total to not count duplicated values

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have a DB which in the simplest of terms is updated with a completed date, delivered amount and a wage earned. there may be 2-5 different campaigns that are updated by this action.
Each row (2-5 of them) receives the date, amount and wage... Now when I output the values for the employee I am using a DISTINCT clause on to only show the area that was delivered (1 of the 2-5) which shows the amount earned by that agent for that delivery...
What I am finding is that the total does not add up correctly if there are any duplications in the delivered amount because that calculates the total earned and my DISTINCT clause causes it to only count one of them.

In the 2 screenshots attached you can see the problem, one total is out by 40.96 (21.76 + 19.20) which are the 2 duplicated values.

If I take away the DISTINCT clause on the SUM it will count all entries which are in the DB which are not shown in the breakdown.

Please can we stick to the question asked, I am aware of MYSQLi, SQL injections and escaping code etc, the whole site is being revamped soon but right now I just need to be paying people correctly... Thanks :-)

```
$grandTotal=$_GET['wage'];

$grandTotal="";    
$sqlquer4=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(DISTINCT wage) FROM campaigns WHERE '$employee' IN (op1, op2, op3, op4, op5, op6, op7, op8) AND period='$period' AND ident='$ident' " );

$wagesCount=mysql_num_rows($sqlquer4); //counts the output
if ($wagesCount > 0 ){
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sqlquer4)){
    $id=$row["id"];
    $grandTotal=$row["SUM(DISTINCT wage)"];
```

*UPDATE *
Sample DB with explanations of the expected results.

```
|   date    |   campaign   |    AREA    |  delivered  |   wage   |
------------------------------------------------------------------
|2017-03-01 |   83BNM1-17  | CENTRAL LB |     546     |  £21.84  |
|2017-03-01 |   34QTR3-17  | CENTRAL LB |     546     |  £21.84  |
|2017-03-01 |  109BELL1-17 | CENTRAL LB |     546     |  £21.84  | 3 CAMPAIGNS TO CENTRAL LB ON 01-03-17 = 1 PAYMENT OF £21.84 (AS INTENDED THE DISTINCT CLAUSE DISPLAYS ONLY 1 ENTRY)
|2017-03-02 |   47URB5-17  |GARDEN HEDGE|     544     |  £21.76  | 
|2017-03-02 |   26PIZZ2-17 |GARDEN HEDGE|     544     |  £21.76  | 
|2017-03-02 |   68ANLA2-17 |GARDEN HEDGE|     544   * |  £21.76  | 3 CAMPAIGNS TO GARDEN HEDGE ON 02-03-17 = 1 PAYMENT OF £21.76 (AS INTENDED THE DISTINCT CLAUSE AGAIN DISPLAYS ONLY 1 ENTRY)
|2017-03-10 |   11MNM5-17  | MEADOW WAY |     384     |  £19.20  |
|2017-03-10 |   5DRAG2-17  | MEADOW WAY |     384   * |  £19.20  | 2 CAMPAIGNS TO MEADOW WAY ON 10-03-17 = 1 PAYMENT OF £19.20 (AS INTENDED THE DISTINCT CLAUSE DISPLAYS 1 ENTRY) 
|2017-03-17 |   85ZEB3-17  | CENTRAL LB |     544     |  £21.76  | 
|2017-03-17 |  108MED3-17  | CENTRAL LB |     544   * |  £21.76  | THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS; £21.76 APPEARS TWICE, ONCE FOR GARDEN HEDGE AND AGAIN FOR CENTRAL ON DIFFERENT DAYS
|2017-03-23 |   83BNM1-17  | MEADOW WAY |     384     |  £19.20  |
|2017-03-23 |   108MED3-17 | MEADOW WAY |     384   * |  £19.20  | THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS AGAIN; £19.20 APPEARS TWICE, BOTH TIMES IT IS FOR MEADOW WAY, HOWEVER THEY ARE ON DIFFERENT DAYS THEREFORE CORRECT.

The DISTINCT clause is preventing the genuine duplicated values to appear in the total.
If I remove the DISTINCT clause all values are counted for each campaign, I need it to calculate the totals (once) for each area on each day allowing duplicate areas and amounts.

What I want to see is 1 total;
21.84 + 21.76 + 19.20 + 21.76 + 19.20 = 103.76

currently what I am seeing is:
62.80 with DISTINCT (103.76 - 19.20 - 21.76)
251.12 without DISTINCT I get the total of every entry in the sample

.
```

[image]

Comment: No screenshots attached

Comment: Can you post sample DB data and the expected result? Maybe build a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: How is that field defined?

Comment: @Forbs I don't understand the screenshot is there on my screen, this is the address on the post edit https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfsaW.jpg

Comment: @jJNevill could you expand?

Comment: @chris85 sample now added as an update, sorry I've never used sqlfiddle

Comment: What are `period` and `ident`? Here's a fiddle of what you provided http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1452/1 (I stripped the pounds because you can't add a varchar.

Comment: @chris85 thank you for that fiddle, $period is the period to pay them in, i.e. Jan, Feb, Mar etc... $ident is basically the year.

Comment: @IanPither Update the fiddle so it has a reproducible example.

Comment: @chris85 I have now solved my issue, it was apparent from the start that DISTINCT would eliminate the duplicates, however, I was then asking the query to allow a duplicate wage entry. I ended up using a simple SUM(wage) clause on a new field (pay) in the dB and made it unique for my 1st campaign only. you helped immensely because I now understand sqlfiddle and that is what solved my problem with lots of trial and error. I'd be happy if you answered the question and I'll make it as solved by you.

Comment: @IanPither Oaky, I think it could have been done with a `group by` but without a clear data structure it wasn't possible to assist you.